# Как сделать кастомную функцию для sidebar?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть собственный скрипт использующий абсолютное позиционирование для сайдбара. Как сделать для него кастомную настройку, чтобы например, если есть класс или data атрибут, то он останавливался у нижней границы контейнера?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $blockBar = $('.js-bar-scroll'),
        positionBlockBar = $blockBar.offset().top,
        blockBarIsAbsolute = 'bar-scroll-is-absolute',
        headerHeight = $('.header-inner').height(),
        footerHeight = $('.footer').height(),
        blockBarHeight = $blockBar.height(),
        $blockHidden = $('.bar-scroll-is-hidden'),
        $blockScrolledHidden = $('.bar-scroll-is-moved-hidden'),
        $blockBarContainer = $('.bar-scroll-container').height();

    function scrollableFilter() {

        var positionScrollTop = $('.bar-scroll-container').offset().top;

        $('.js-bar-scroll-to-top').on('click', function(){
            $('html, body')
                .stop()
                .animate({
                scrollTop: positionScrollTop
            }, 300);
        });

        if($(this).scrollTop() > positionBlockBar - headerHeight + blockBarHeight) {
            var fixedPositionBlockBar = $(window).scrollTop() - positionBlockBar + headerHeight,
                fixedPositionBottom = $blockBarContainer - blockBarHeight;
            $blockBar.addClass(blockBarIsAbsolute);
            $blockBar.css('top', fixedPositionBlockBar);
            $blockScrolledHidden.css({
                'visibility': 'hidden',
                'height': '0',
                'padding': '0'
            });
            $blockHidden
                .fadeIn()
                .addClass('flex-important');
        } else {
            $blockBar.removeClass(blockBarIsAbsolute);
            $blockBar.css('top', '');
            $blockScrolledHidden.css({
                'visibility': '',
                'height': '',
                'padding': ''
            });
            $blockHidden
                .css('display', 'none')
                .removeClass('flex-important');
        }
    }

    var $windowHeight = $(window).height();

    if ($(window).width() <= 1366) {
            scrollableFilter(false);
    } else {
        $(window).on('scroll', function(){
            scrollableFilter(true);
        });
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        if ($(window).width() <= 1366) {
            scrollableFilter(false);
        } else {
            $(window).on('scroll', function(){
                scrollableFilter(true);
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Стоит начать с того, чтобы выложить разметку, к которой этот скрипт применять. Мало вероятно, что кто-то, прочитав код, представит в голове html и то как этот код изменить.

Comment: @AndrewB да, сделаю